# Why does this CosmosDB SQL Query fail when run from C# code?

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am running this query from the azure portal Data Explorer in CosmosDB and it works fine

```
SELECT COUNT(UniqueIDValues) AS UniqueCount
FROM ( 
        SELECT DISTINCT c.id 
        FROM c 
        JOIN i IN c.ItemsInBasket 
        WHERE c.Brand = 'xxx' 
        AND i.Item.PromotionName = 'PromOnePiece_20201029_202001_25'
        AND c.IsRedeemed = false
        AND c.IsDeleted = false
    ) AS UniqueIDValues
```

It produces the expected result

```
[
    {
        "UniqueCount": 4
    }
]
```

but if I run the same query from an azure function like this

```
FeedIterator setIterator = _container.GetItemQueryStreamIterator(
               $"SELECT COUNT(UniqueIDValues) AS UniqueCount " +
               $"FROM ( " +
               $"SELECT DISTINCT c.id " +
               $"FROM c " +
               $"JOIN i IN c.ItemsInBasket " +
               $"WHERE c.Brand = 'xxx' " +
               $"AND i.Item.PromotionName = 'PromOnePiece_20201029_202001_25' " +
               $"AND c.IsRedeemed = false " +
               $"AND c.IsDeleted = false " +
               $" ) AS UniqueIDValues",
              requestOptions: new QueryRequestOptions()
              {
                  PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(brand),
                  MaxConcurrency = -1,
                  MaxItemCount = -1
              });

            while (setIterator.HasMoreResults)
            {
                using (ResponseMessage response = await setIterator.ReadNextAsync())
                {
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.Content))
                        using (JsonTextReader jtr = new JsonTextReader(sr))
                        {
                            JsonSerializer jsonSerializer = new JsonSerializer();
                            JObject items = jsonSerializer.Deserialize<JObject>(jtr);

                            numberOfPromotions = (decimal?)items.SelectToken("Documents[0].UniqueCount");

                            return numberOfPromotions ?? 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

This returns 0 results and I cannot figure out why, I have checked all variables they are correct, I even hardcoded them and it still do not work when run through the SDK.

What am I missing here?

Comment: What is the value of `brand` when you assign it to your partition key? Is it the name of the property you're using as a partition key, or the value that should be present in the partition key's property? (it needs to be the latter)

Comment: @DavidMakogon the value we have 100s of other queries working using the exact same structure, just this one with a SUB query fails all,other works fine

Comment: Are you querying the right container and account? Pls check.

Comment: @singhh-msft yes for sure

Answer (score 0):

***Assuming**, the same code runs for other queries*, there can be below reasons for it to not work:

1. It is querying at **wrong place** (container or account).
2. The **query** generated by code is **wrong** (copy the query value using debugger and run that instead in Azure Data explorer).
3. By the time you read the records, they are deleted by some other app.
4. You are querying **wrong partition key**(the partition key you are querying does not have any such records).

Comment: I would suggest this list be posted as a comment, not as an answer (since we have no idea what the actual issue is).

Comment: These are the possible reasons I can think of. I believe one of them shall be true.

Comment: @singhh-msft how do I copy the query value? I have checked everything else and it’s right but how do I check the actual query value generated by the code?

Comment: Debug and hover over `setIterator`. One of the parameters must be the query you are creating. Or simply create a dummy string with the value you are generating for query and hover over that variable to see it's value

Comment: @singhh-msft - the OP is now asking you clarifications for debugging, as a comment to this answer (which, again, isn't really an answer). This is why this should have been a comment under the question.